# SQL Where Clause condition

Tags: c#, sql, where-clause

In sql where clause; if `pv.SalePrice` is `null`, I want to use `pv.Price`.
How can I do this?

```
WHERE    
    @FilterRangePriceValueMin < pv.SalePrice OR pv.SalePrice is null
     AND (@FilterRangePriceValueMax > pv.SalePrice OR pv.SalePrice is null)
```

Comment: You can use case inside where clause.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function to try items for `NULL` in order, and then take the first non-null one for comparison. You can also use `BETWEEN` to avoid writing out the call twice:

```
WHERE
    COALESCE(pv.SalePrice, pv.Price)
    BETWEEN @FilterRangePriceValueMin AND @FilterRangePriceValueMax
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) which returns the first nonnull expression in its arguments.

```
WHERE    
   @FilterRangePriceValueMin < COALESCE(pv.SalePrice, pv.Price) 
   AND @FilterRangePriceValueMax > COALESCE(pv.SalePrice, pv.Price)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement

```
@FilterRangePriceValueMin < (CASE WHEN pv.SalePrice IS NULL THEN pv.Price ELSE pv.SalePrice END) OR pv.SalePrice is null
AND (@FilterRangePriceValueMax > (CASE WHEN pv.SalePrice IS NULL THEN pv.Price ELSE pv.SalePrice END) OR pv.SalePrice is null)
```

Or you can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

> Returns the first nonnull expression among its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

this may be a stretch, since prices are usually not indexed and are not usually good index candidates.  However, if you do have a good usable index on pv.SalePrice and another good usable index on pv.Price and your table is large, a **`UNION`** on this will run much faster than a COALESCE:

```
SELECT
   ...
   FROM ...
   WHERE pv.SalePrice>=@FilterRangePriceValueMin 
     AND pv.SalePrice<=@FilterRangePriceValueMax
UNION
SELECT
   ...
   FROM ...
   WHERE pv.Price>=@FilterRangePriceValueMin
     AND pv.Price<=@FilterRangePriceValueMax
```

The idea is that two index queries will be faster than a complete table scan.  Also, it is best to use `UNION ALL` if possible, but I can't tell (from limited info in question) if you'll get duplicates or not.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the case clause.

```
CASE WHEN pv.SalePrice IS NULL THEN pv.SalePrice ELSE ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you, I don't try but may be it can be useful for you.

```
(pv.SalePrice is not null and  (@FilterRangePriceValueMin < pv.SalePrice   AND @FilterRangePriceValueMax > pv.SalePrice ))
or 
(pv.SalePrice is null and  (@FilterRangePriceValueMin < pv.Price AND (@FilterRangePriceValueMax > pv.Price ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `IFNULL`---------> `MYSQL`

```
WHERE
    IFNULL(pv.SalePrice, pv.Price)
    BETWEEN @FilterRangePriceValueMin AND @FilterRangePriceValueMax
```

`NVL` ---------------------------> `ORACLE`

```
WHERE
    NVL(pv.SalePrice, pv.Price)
    BETWEEN @FilterRangePriceValueMin AND @FilterRangePriceValueMax
```

`ISNULL` ---------------------------> `SQL SERVER`

```
WHERE
    ISNULL(pv.SalePrice, pv.Price)
    BETWEEN @FilterRangePriceValueMin AND @FilterRangePriceValueMax
```